# What exactly does Adobe Switchboard do?

Tags: bloatware

I hate bloatware, but I needed Adobe to sign PDFs and edit Illustrator files.

UPDATE: I now sign PDFs with pdfescape.com if I don't care about the digital signature, and I edit (simple) Illustrator files with Inkscape.

Installing Adobe CS5.5 brings on a bunch of crap I most likely don't need, and part of that is a service called *Adobe Switchboard*, for which (of course) Adobe has [no clear documentation](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/search/index.cfm?term=switchboard).

The only information I found was on eHow, but I generally distrust DemandMedia properties.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Adobe Switchboard was an experimental Adobe technology which allowed Adobe AIR apps to control CS5 applications. According to [John Nack's blog](http://blogs.adobe.com/jnack/2008/06/drive_the_creative_suite_through_air.html)

> SwitchBoard is a Flex library that allows you to extend an AIR app by giving you access to the ExtendScript DOMs for the Creative Suite apps.  Your AIR app can now easily establish two-way communication with Photoshop, Illustrator, InDesign and Bridge.

However, Adobe Switchboard was [discontinued](http://blogs.adobe.com/labs/archives/2010/04/switchboard_rem.html) and is no longer relevant:

> Adobe will not be directly delivering a replacement technology in CS5, but we will use what we have learned to add more capability to the Adobe Creative Suite SDK in the future. Adobe does not support the use of the SwitchBoard technology in CS5. The SwitchBoard technology was removed on April 30, 2010 and is no longer hosted on Labs.

Most likely, you can disable and remove that service. I do not believe it will break anything if you remove it, but keep a backup just in case.

Comment: Funny how none of the Adobe updates cared to remove that service.

Comment: They can't just remove something like that because someone somewhere will have used it for something important (to them at least) and would find it a major inconvenience.